# When subsetting in R is it necessary to include `which` or can I just put a logical test?

Tags: r, subset

Say I have a data frame `df` and want to subset it based on the value of column a.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 5:8)
df
```

Is it necessary to include a `which` function in the brackets or can I just include the logical test?

```
df[df$a == "2",]
#  a b
#2 2 6
df[which(df$a == "2"),]
#  a b
#2 2 6
```

It seems to work the same either way... I was getting some strange results in a large data frame (i.e., getting empty rows returned as well as the correct ones) but once I cleaned the environment and reran my script it worked fine.

Comment: Try browsing https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html if you're curious about this sort of thing. Probably the "index vectors" section.

Comment: `df$a == "2"` returns a logical vector, while `which` returns indices. If there are missing values in the vector, the first approach will include them in the returned value, but `which` will exclude them. Try `x=c(1,NA,2)`, then `x[x==2]` and `x[which(x==2)]`. Also take a look at the actual indexing vectors (`x==2`) and `which(x==2)`.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks for the clarification about NA values - I didn't realize they were included when not using `which`. That's exactly why I was getting an unexpected result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df$a == "2"` returns a logical vector, while `which(df$a=="2")` returns indices. If there are missing values in the vector, the first approach will include them in the returned value, but `which` will exclude them.

For example:

```
x=c(1,NA,2,10)

x[x==2]
```

> ```
> [1] NA  2
> ```

```
x[which(x==2)]
```

> ```
> [1] 2
> ```

```
x==2
```

> ```
> [1] FALSE    NA  TRUE FALSE
> ```

```
which(x==2)
```

> ```
> [1] 3
> ```